# Equation 33.5 in Numerical Linear Algebra by Trefethen and Bau (span of $\mathcal{K}_n$ equals column space of $Q_n$).

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

On page 253 of *Numerical Linear Algebra* by Trefethen and Bau, equation 33.5 states that

$$
\mathcal{K}_n = \langle b, Ab, \dots, A^{n-1}b \rangle = \langle q_1, q_2, \dots, q_n \rangle \subseteq \mathbb{C}^m
$$

where $\mathcal{K}_n$ is the $n$th-dimensional Krylov subspace generated by $A$ and $q_j$ ($j = 1, \dots, n$) are the columns of a unitary matrix $Q_n$.

They deduce this from equation 33.4 which states that

$$
Aq_n = h_{1n}q_1 + \cdots + h_{nn}q_n + h_{n+1,n}q_{n+1}
$$

which comes from the matrix equation $AQ_n = Q_{n+1}\tilde{H}_n$ where $\tilde{H}_n$ is an $(n+1)\times n$ upper Hessenberg matrix.

Why does 33.4 lead to 33.5? I can see that it's plausible given the recurrent behavior, but I don't see the connection between $q_j$ and $b$ for example.

Comment: you can try to write $q_{n+1}$ as a span of all $q_i$ and $A q_n$, then use induction.